# Powershell v2.0 - querying XML nodes

Tags: xml, powershell, selectsinglenode

I'm having trouble trying to return a list of XMLs and determining whether each has a particular node present.

We have a list of Employee files, that either do or do not have a particular XML node called Password. If the Password node is present in the XML, then it is a New Employee, otherwise it will be an Update. In my script attempt below, it seems to only return the same result, knowing that there are variations of the XML for testing.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<EnterpriseDocument CreationTimestamp="2016-07-18T09:44:39">
  -<BusinessUnitList>
    -<BusinessUnit id="4086">
     -<User id="1234567" lastName="Sample" firstName="Sample" password="Password1234">
     </User>
    </BusinessUnit>
 </BusinessUnitList>
```

```
$Path = gc 'c:\temp\importexport\*.xml'
Foreach ($xml in $Path) {
    $xmldata = [xml]$xml
    $Password = $XMLData.SelectSingleNode("//BusinessUnitList/BusinessUnit/User/Password")
    If ($Password)   
        {Write-host "New Employee"}
    Else
        {write-host "Employee Update"}
}
```

I have tried variations and experimented but can't seem to get the mixed results I am looking for. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: In your XML, `password` isn't a node, it's an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Eris, the `password` value is not an element/node, but an *attribute*.

You'll want to check two things - that the node exists, and that the attribute is present:

```
if(($User = $XML.SelectSingleNode('//User')) -and $User.HasAttribute('password'))
{
    Write-Host 'password found!'
}
else
{
    Write-Host 'no password!'
}
```

Comment: I'm getting *Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlDocument] doesn't contain a method named 
'HasAttribute'*. MSDN doesn't recognise HasAttribute as a Powershell method.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @JDGEEK What exactly are you doing? `SelectSingleNode()` doesn't return an `XmlDocument` object.

Comment: OK so I have now taken a different approach, and I have a different question which I shall create in a separate thread. The reason for this, is because I am comparing files in a directory, based on xml content, using PS, against files recorded in a SQL database. However, the original XML is not saved in SQL, so in order to apply the correct filter to the SQL query, I have to feed in the pre-defined PS query to it.

Comment: @JDGEEK If you have another question, feel free to [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you want help with why this answer doesn't work for you, please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38441532/edit) with an update describing exactly what you did and how it failed